# Panel movement with respect to player

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: Car Racing]

I followed this tutorial on youtube - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-CN2DXqJjM for making minimap and which is working absolutely fine. But i have enemy car also for which i have made panel (red dot). How can i synchronize the speed of enemy car with respect of panel (red dot)

Though i have no idea how shall i make it move. Can anyone help me ???

Update - I made a camera and Child it with the player car and assigned a Rendered Texture to Camera. then i made a Canvas -> Panel, So when Playercar moves, Panel(green dot) moves..Works fine

But i dont know how to make EnemyPanel movement (Red-dot) inside the same camera view

Here is simple code

```
void Start () {
    position = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("WaypointCar").transform.position;    // Enemy Car..
        }       

        void Update () {
                transform.position = position;}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the red dot in the minimap or the Speedometer? If it's the red dot in the minimap then you can get the position of the red dot and assign the position of the car to it. You did not put the minimap  code in your question or mention what type of object the red dot is, so it's really hard to help you from here.

Comment: Yes, its a red dot in the minimap. That reddot is Panel (UI Element) . I have assigned the position of the car to the position of the reddot. The Car is moving, but the red is stable at its position. i followed the above youtube tutorial, which says about playercar movement only. i am adding the code. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you followed did the last part wrong. I am talking about the last part ([3:40](https://youtu.be/3-CN2DXqJjM?t=221)) where a Panel should be created.

Don't do that part. Delete that panel if you have already created one.

**STEP 1**:

Create a layer called **Minimap**.

**STEP 2**:

**A**.Go to *GameObject* --> *3D Object* --> *Sphere*. Name it *GreenTracker* and change the color to red.

**B**.Change the *GreenTracker* Object's layer to *Minimap*.

**C**.Make the *GreenTracker* Sphere the child of of the Player car then position *GreenTracker* Sphere to the position of the player car.

Do the-same thing for the enemy car.

**A**.Go to *GameObject* --> *3D Object* --> *Sphere*. Name it *RedTracker* and change the color to green.

**B**.Change the *RedTracker* Object's layer to *Minimap*.

**C**.Make the *RedTracker* Sphere the child of of the other car (Enemy?) then position *RedTracker* Sphere to the position of the other car.

**STEP 3**:

**A**.Select the *Main Camera* then on its Culling Mask, make sure that *Minimap* layer is *de-selected*.

*By doing this, the Main Camera will **not** show the red and green trackers.* We only want the *Minimap Camera* to show this.

**B**.Select the *Minimap Camera* created at [0:33](https://youtu.be/3-CN2DXqJjM?t=33) then on its Culling Mask, make sure that **only** *Minimap* layer is *selected*.

*By doing this, the Minimap Camera will **only** show the red and green trackers.* You can add more layers to show in the Minimap if you want.

That's it. This should work fine.

If you are still confused or encounter problems, please take a look at [this](http://blog.theknightsofunity.com/implementing-minimap-unity/) post for how to do this from start to finish with visual images.

Comment: Hey, Thanks i got it. Is there any camera or way where i can zppm on each car through camera and let the other remaining part be small